Redis go client database integration
I am using Redis Cloud console for database , I did not download Redis Client on my system as I was just trying to use it for the first time for some personal project , I am trying to connect to it , I am using redis Go client ,** first off** in the Redis Cloud console when I try to connect to my free database , in the "select your client" option I don't see Go mentioned in the dropdown , although it is there in the documentation , secondly I took help from documentation and from a tutorial for nodejs client connection and tried connecting it to my host address and port but it is not connecting .
This is the error I got  : 2024/04/17 14:50:17 Failed to connect to Redis: dial tcp [::1]:6379: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
I am not trying to connect to 6379 port , my specified database port is different which is specified in the address .
This is the snippets of the code I am trying to run :
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

// the main function for connection  :
func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading .env file")
    }

    // Connect to Redis
    rdb = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     os.Getenv("REDIS_ADDRESS"),
        Password: os.Getenv("REDIS_PW"),
        DB:       0, // use default DB
    })

    // Test Redis connection
    _, err = rdb.Ping(context.Background()).Result() // Provide context
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to connect to Redis: %v", err)
    }

    //I am using env variables in a separate file .
}


How about checking your env variables?

ex1. Wrong REDIS_ADDRESS
ex2. Not properly setting your redis in the cloud
and so on..

I checked your code by using miniredis which is the test server for redis at Golang unit test. https://github.com/alicebob/miniredis
There is no problem in your code itself
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/alicebob/miniredis/v2"
    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)

func main() {
    mockRedis, _ := miniredis.Run()

    redisClient := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr: mockRedis.Addr(),
        DB:   0,
    })

    log.Printf("MockRedis Addr: %s\n", mockRedis.Addr())

    result, err := redisClient.Ping(context.Background()).Result()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to connect to Redis: %v", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Succeeded to connect to Redis: %v\n", result)
    }
}

The log is
2024/04/20 10:34:19 MockRedis Addr: 127.0.0.1:51314
2024/04/20 10:34:19 Succeeded to connect to Redis: PONG


Thanks for replying , I rechecked the address and the password , they are fine , maybe its the latter thing , I am not setting up the cloud right , as I mentioned before I don't see an option for "GO" in the dropdown , is that the issue ?? can you check this image here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OBms-3qf6pWGvoTPlhmTzdRQq6OkhyZq/view?usp=sharing

@chaosss I see. I have redis experience in my network but not in the cloud. I want to ask few questions. (1) Your client and your server is in the same network? because your error showed Failed to conenct. (2) What code it shows when you select Python in select your client?
